# How to split string if fist come UNION then split by UNION , If come EXCEPT then split by EXCEPT and so on

Tags: c#

I have a input string:

`"SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt UNION SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses EXCEPT  SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM XYZ UNION ALL  SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM PQR INTERSECT  SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM ABC".`

and I want output string in this format:

```
"UNION 
SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt  
EXCEPT 
SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses  
UNION ALL 
SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM XYZ   
INTERSECT 
SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM PQR   
SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM ABC"
```

I want to do it recursively if I found union first then split line by union i.e

"SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt UNION SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses EXCEPT SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM XYZ"

then it should be added in array is 
"SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt UNION"

then for next loop it checks for union if not found then checks for EXCEPT and split the string and adds

"SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses EXCEPT" in array 
and so on.

I want final output is like

"UNION 
    SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt
    EXCEPT 
    SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses
    UNION ALL 
    SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM XYZ
    INTERSECT 
    SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM PQR
    SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM ABC"

My code is :

```
                if (sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().StartsWith("SQLSELECT") && (sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("UNION") || sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("UNION ALL") || sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("INTERSECT") || sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("EXCEPT") || sTempLine.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("MINUS")))
                {
                    index = sTempLine.ToUpper().Trim().IndexOf("UNION");
                    //sTempLine = sTempLine.Trim().Substring(0,index);

                    for (int i=0; i < sTempLine.Length; i++)
                    {
                        index = sTempLine.ToUpper().IndexOf("UNION");
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("UNION"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 5));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 5));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 5);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("UNION ALL"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 9));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 9));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 9);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("INTERSECT"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 9));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 9));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 9);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("EXCEPT"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 6));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 6));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 6);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("MINUS"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 5));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 5));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 5);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }

                sbFileWrite.AppendLine(sTempLine + ClsGlobal.Space_Const+ sLineNumber);
            }
```

Comment: And what´s your problem on doing so? Have you googled "replace substring from string"? Should give you the answer.

Comment: Yes but It is not working.

Comment: What isn't working?  There is zero indication in this question that you have tried anything at all.

Comment: even the question is frustratingly unclear.

Comment: index = sTempLine.ToUpper().IndexOf("UNION");
                        if (sTempLine.Contains("UNION"))
                        {
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(0, index + 5));
                                listInput.Add(sTempLine.Substring(index + 5));
                                sTempLine = sTempLine.Substring(index + 5);
                            }
                        }  I tried this code.

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code there.  Code in comments is not readable.  And please, format your code.

Comment: As far as I can see all you want to replace "Select" by "Union". What´s the problem on using `myString.Replace("SELECT", "UNION)"`?

Comment: I want to do it recursively if I found union first then split line by union i.e SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt UNION SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses EXCEPT SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM XYZ" then it should be added in array is "SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, department_name "Department" FROM tttt UNION" then for next loop it checks for union if not found then checks for  EXCEPT and split the string and adds "SQLSELECT SELECT location_id, warehouse_name FROM warehouses EXCEPT" in array and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string input = "SASASA EXCEPT ASASA UNION"; // test input here is your input string which is a sql query


            int UnionIndex = input.IndexOf("UNION");

            int ExceptIndex = input.IndexOf("EXCEPT");


            List<string> SplitArray = new List<string>();  // here is the list with the sub strings

            if (UnionIndex < ExceptIndex)
            {
                SplitArray = input.Split(new[] { "UNION" },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }
            else if (ExceptIndex < UnionIndex)
            {
                SplitArray= input.Split(new[] { "EXCEPT" },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }
```